# Regular expression for indian train seat numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out appropriate regex for indian train seat numbers. For e.g. S10 43, B4 24 etc. I know different trains have different number of seats and coaches but a general regex will work for me. I was trying something like this:

```
[A|B|C|S][1-15][1-72]$
```

But this is not working. I also didn't find link to all types of seats in train. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
[ABCS](?:1[0-5]|[1-9])\s+(?:[1-9]|[1-6][0-9]|7[0-2])$
```

Limiting to a given number range (1-15 and 1-72) makes it a little more complicated (as above) - it will be a lot simpler if you just accept 1- or 2-digit numbers:

```
[ABCS]\d\d?\s+\d\d?$
```

But that will match `A99 99` which apparently isn't valid

Comment: I tried running your regex. It is giving error. Here is the link: http://ideone.com/s6wsz6

Comment: turns out this is working fine:
[ABCS](?:1[0-5]|[0-9])\s+(?:0-9|[1-6][0-9]|7[0-2])$

Comment: Sorry - missed the closing paren. Glad you caught it. If this answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Except if `A00` is valid, you must replace `[0-9]` by `[1-9]`, also, in the second part replace `0-9` by `[1-9]`